# "Этот проект не поддерживается в комплекте разработки C#" что делать?

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio-code

Больше месяца все работало нормально, и тут начало писать в VS Core подобное:

> 2023-10-04 12:46:55.827 [error] Не удалось загрузить проект "c:\Проекты\Тест\New Unity Project 1\Assembly-CSharp.csproj". One or more errors occurred. (Этот проект не поддерживается в комплекте разработки C#.)
> 2023-10-04 12:46:55.981 [error] Не удалось загрузить проект "c:\Проекты\Тест\New Unity Project 1\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj". One or more errors occurred. (Этот проект не поддерживается в комплекте разработки C#.)
> 2023-10-04 12:46:56.122 [info] Инициализация системы проектов завершена. Загружено столько проектов: 0, не удалось загрузить: 2.

Расширения не добавлял, VS Core переустановил с прошлой версией, расширения прошлых версий поставил, но всеравно вылезает эта ошибка. Что делать?

Comment: Посмотрите в csproj, под какой .NET проект и скачайте соответствующий SDK